# What is the value of $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f}?$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Theorem $10.8$

> Suppose  $\gamma $ is  a regular closed  curve. If $f$  is meromorphic inside and on $\gamma$  and  contains no zeroes  or oples  on $\gamma$ , and if

> $\mathbb{Z}$= number of zeroes  of  $f$  inside  $\gamma$ ( a  zero of order k being  counted  $k$  times

> $\mathbb{P}=$ number  of poles of $f$  inside $\gamma$ (again with multiplicity)

then  $$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f} = \mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{P}$$

---

**My question** :What is the value of $\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f}?$

**My answer** :$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f}=2k$

---

**My attempt** :At  a simple pole  $a$ , the residue of $f$ is given by  $Res(f,a)=\lim_{z\to a}f(z)$

$$\implies Res(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a)=\lim_{z\to a} (z-a) \frac{k}{z-a}+ \lim_{z\to a} (z-a)\frac{g'(z)}{g(z)}$$
$$\implies Res(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a)= k$$

Similarly ,
$$
 f(z) = (z-a)^{-k} g(z)
$$
where $g$ is holomorphic and non-zero in a neighborhood of $z=a$. Therefore
$$
 \frac{f'(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{-k}{z-a} + \text{ something holomorphic }
$$
in a neighborhood of $z=a$, so that
$$
\operatorname{Res}\left(\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a\right) = -k \, .
$$

Therefore

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\gamma} \frac{f'}{f}= \sum_k Res (\frac{f'(z)}{f(z)},a_k)=\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{P}=k-(-k)=2k$$

Is it correct ?

Comment: I do not understand your argument. Why should $\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{P}$ be equal to $k-(-k)$?

Comment: A simple example: $f(z) = (z-1)^2/z^3$ has a double zero at $z=1$, and a triple pole at $z=0$. In this case we have $\mathbb{Z}-\mathbb{P}= 2 - 3 = -1$.

Comment: @MartinR the number of zeroes of $f=k=\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Every zero and every pole counts separately. If you have three zeros with multiplicities $1, 2, 13$ then $\Bbb Z = 1+2+13$.

Comment: okay @MartinR .